# Are all iOS and Android development capabilities of VS 2015 Enterprise available in Win 8.1?

Tags: android, ios, visual-studio, windows-phone-8

Are all iOS and Android related development capabilities of VS 2015 Enterprise available when running on Win 8.1 64 bit or do I have to use Win 10 as a development machine?

Sorry for the lame question, but it's hard to filter out the real facts in the marketing and sales buzz/noise.

Comment: Edited out the request for links/product recommendations to keep this on topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the iOS based development, still seems to be experimental at this stage, moreover require Mac machine to be used as remote agent.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn707598(v=vs.140).aspx#InstallForiOS

Its probably something to show where VS is heading. At this time, its limited has restriction, as from link above

## Win 8.1 vs Win 10

Kindly check this link 
https://www.visualstudio.com/visual-studio-2015-compatibility-vs

> When running on OS earlier than Windows 10, some Visual Studio features for Windows Universal development may be degraded.

So iOS and Android development should work same on both, yet Windows Universal development can have limitation on Windows 8.1.

Comment: Yes I know about Mac/XCode. The main question is about 1) Win 8.1 vs Win 10, 2) Optional Non MS source of info